# How to convert string to Boolean in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I came across this question for the interview. I had to convert the string to Boolean and return the Boolean value

For ex `s="3>1>5" => false`

I tried using

```
ans= bool(s)
```

But I always get the answer as True even though the above example gives False if we don't pass it as a string

Comment: If you read the docs for `bool()` you'll see that it doesn't evaluate the contents of a string passed to it.

Comment: If you are not allowed to use `eval`, then you have to do full-scale parsing - unless the expressions in the strings have very simple, regular structure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be looking for `eval(string)`

```py
>>> eval("3>1>5")
False
```

Comment: Mandatory caveat that [eval really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).

Comment: @jarmod indeed, feel free to edit my answer if you'd like to add that